# switching from grid view to list view using MixItUp jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, gridview, portfolio

I'm using jquery MixItUp on my website to display images and videos.
It works fine in a grid view, filtering is also ok, but I don't understand how by clicking a button I can switch view from grid to list, can't find the solution...

Here is my html :

```
<div class="bloc_1_medias">
    <ul id="Grid">
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix videos"><iframe width="233" height="133" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix videos"><iframe width="233" height="133" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix videos"><iframe width="233" height="133" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
        <li class="mix videos"><iframe width="233" height="133" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gg1RBO1Cj4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        <li class="mix photos"><img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-01.jpg" class="photo_medias"></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<span class="medias_filtre_titre">Filter by : </span>
<span class="filter" data-filter="photos">PHOTOS</span> | 
<span class="filter" data-filter="videos">VIDEOS</span> | 
<span class="filter" data-filter="photos videos">DATES</span>

<div class="switch_medias">
    <img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/grid.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:blue;padding:5px" id="GoGrid" class="button.layout"/> | 
    <img src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/list.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:blue;padding:5px" id="GoList" class="button.layout"/>
</div>
```

I'm trying to switch to list when clicking on "list.jpg" image and switch to grid when clicking on "grid.jpg".

I don't know what to add to my Js and Css.

here is my JS :

```
$(function(){


  $('#Grid').mixitup()({

    layoutMode: 'grid',
    targetDisplayGrid: 'inline-block',
    targetDisplayList: 'block',
  });

});
```

and a jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/aaWLJ/

Answer (score 0):

You had a few syntax errors in your jQuery.  I have corrected them and you can also see the implementation of the "view switch" on [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaWLJ/2/).

```
$(function(){

  $('#Grid').mixitup({

    layoutMode: 'grid',
    listClass: 'list',
    gridClass: 'grid',
    targetDisplayGrid: 'inline-block',
    targetDisplayList: 'block'
  });

    $('img#GoList').on('click', function(){
        $('#Grid').mixitup('toList');
    });

    $('img#GoGrid').on('click', function(){
        $('#Grid').mixitup('toGrid');
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @RossG. now is there a way to change class of my images ? to apply a larger width when displayed on list ? that's gonna be more difficult I guess for the videos, if you have any idea it's more than welcome !